# Как одним layout-ом отображать переменное число view?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Начал осваивать разработку под Android, пишу приложение для онлайн курсов. Уроки будут состоять из текста, видео и картинок. Но ведь некоторые уроки будут состоять из картинок, некоторые нет, также с видео.  Не могу понять как реализовать xml layout, если иногда урок содержит 2 видео, или картинки, или совсем не содержит видео. Хранить в БД для каждого урока свой layout, или как?

Comment: можно добавлять view построенное по заданному шаблону динамически программным путём через LayoutInflater

Comment: Так ведь и шаблонов может быть много? Например, иногда, видео может быть в начале урока, или по середине текста( + картинка внизу) и т.д..

Comment: https://androidexample.com/Dynamically_Create_View_Elements__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=115

Comment: я если честно никогда сам не делал так, только в теории знаю, но думаю, может быть много шаблонов

Comment: В приведенном примере просто в цикле добавляются, но по сути, вьюхи одинаковые, и идут групами(TextView, TextView, Button). А мне интерестно как хранить и выводить разные уроки(ведь в каждом уроке будет разное количество view, иногда будет одно видео, иногда два, иногда картинки; да и разное расположение относительного текста), думаю в цикле выводить не выйдет, ведь не всегда будет отображаться в заданом порядке.

Comment: Структуру урока вам все равно придется хранить в том или ином виде (в БД например), а отрисовывать можно и программно.

Comment: А можно хранить для каждого урока свой layout? И если да, то хорошо ли так делать?)

Comment: @РостиславХлань что мешает хранить информация о самих уроках? Ведь зная количество видео/изображений/др. в уроке, можно генерировать динамически любой layout.

Comment: понял, спасибо)

Comment: наверное проще будет сверстать уроки в html и выводить в WebView, чем генерировать нативный layout индивидуально для каждого урока.

Comment: Тогда структура layout-а будет одиноковой, только в webview будем разный параметр передавать, верно?